# How to implement simple 2D translation on OpenGL ES 2.0 using OpenTK for android

Tags: android, matrix, xamarin.android, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

I am trying to add the translation to a simple example of drawing a triangle using OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android. I have created translation matrix with 0 translation in all directions which should be the identity matrix. When I remove the multiplication from vertex shader triangle renders fine. However when I try to add some transformation(even identity) nothing is rendered. I think it is something about sending matrix data to the shader. GL.UniformMatrix 4 only takes float as attributes and I cant convert Matrix4 to float array. At the end I desperately created float array for identity matrix and passed it using GL.UniformMAtrix4 however nothing is rendered again.

Can anyone with the experience help me out please.

```
        Matrix4 uvMat = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

        // Vertex and fragment shaders
        string vertexShaderSrc =  "attribute vec4 vPosition;    \n" + 
            "uniform mat4 uvMat;                    \n" +
            "void main()                  \n" +
            "{                            \n" +
            "   gl_Position = uvMat*vPosition;  \n" +
            "}                            \n";

        string fragmentShaderSrc = "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "void main()                                  \n" +
            "{                                            \n" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vec4 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  \n" +
            "}                                            \n";

        int vertexShader = LoadShader (All.VertexShader, vertexShaderSrc );
        int fragmentShader = LoadShader (All.FragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc );
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        if (program == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException ("Unable to create program");

        GL.AttachShader (program, vertexShader);
        GL.AttachShader (program, fragmentShader);

        GL.BindAttribLocation (program, 0, "vPosition");
        GL.LinkProgram (program);

        float[] matTrans = new float[] {1,0,0,0,
                              0,1,0,0,
                              0,0,1,0,
            0,0,0,1};

        int uniMatLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation (program, "uvMat");
        Console.WriteLine (uniMatLoc.ToString());
        GL.UniformMatrix4 (uniMatLoc, 16, false, matTrans);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `UniformMatrix4` is the number of matrices, not the number of elements in the matrix. So the call should be:

```
GL.UniformMatrix4(uniMatLoc, 1, false, matTrans);
```

Comment: Is there any way to use Matrix4 instead of float[] ?

Comment: I don't know. It was asked in this (relatively old) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375076/monotouch-opentk-and-uniformmatrix4.